# Передача параметров между session

Tags: java, web-apps, java-ee, jsp

Добрый день.
Такая ситуация: есть 2 веб-приложения (крутятся на tomcat). В одном из приложений на jsp странице использую

```
forward(request, response)
```

Предварительно заполнив request необходимыми параметрами (напр.: имя пользователя).
В итоге получаю новую страницу, старый URL и два объекта сессии с разными id (для каждого из двух веб-приложений).
После того как кликаю на какой либо ссылке перехожу непосредственно в контекст второго приложения. Соответственно обновляется объект request, ну а переданные параметры пропадают.

Вопрос такой: как сохранить эти параметры в **выбранную** сессию (одну из двух), чтобы при переходе в другой контекст я не потерял параметры?

Answer (score 1):

Надо установить атрибут `crossContext=true` в настроечном файле контекстов Tomcat - `context.xml`

[См. документацию](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/context.html)

Comment: Установлено, с этим уже разобрались :)
Дело в том, что у каждого веб-приложения сессии "откладывают" свою ID в куки, которые имеют свой путь (path) при одинаковом домене. Вопрос в том, каким образом доступиться к сессии другого приложения.
Как я понял встроенных в приложение средств нету (необходимо самому писать session listener, который потом позволит забрать сессию по ID). 
Проблема в том, что необходимо передать параметр уникальный для текущей сессии, а значит через контекст это не сделать - ибо он меняется для всех.